# Android contact disappears when I add new phone number to it

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-compatibility

This code causes the contact to disappear. I'm trying to add another phone number to a contact

```
public void addNumber(Context cos, String contactID, String newPhoneNumber){
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();


ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                        .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+"=?", new String[]{contactID})
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA, newPhoneNumber).build());

                try {
                    cos.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert or update the number? The code tries to  do an update.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
      new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId)
      .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
      .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "1-800-GOOG-411")
      .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM)
      .withValue(Phone.LABEL, "free directory assistance")
      .build());
 getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```